# CentOS Public Mirror

Tags: centos, rsync, mirror

I would like to use rsync command for create a CentOS public mirror server but I got an error on rsync command

```
rsync -aqzH --delete msync.centos.org::CentOS /path/to/local/mirror/root
```

Error :

```
@ERROR: Unknown module 'CentOS'
```

Reference :
[How to create public mirrors for CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreatePublicMirrors)

How can if fix this ?

Comment: Try lowercase `centos`.

Answer (score 0):

the referenced wiki page says:

> For your first mirror synchronization, you must use one of the
>   external mirrors providing rsync access. You can find that list here:
>   https://centos.org/download/mirrors/

This means you must do your **initial** sync from some other public mirror, not msync.centos.org. After you have finished the sync and your web server is ready, you can email your mirror info to the mailing list. If everything is OK, your mirror will be added to the list of public CentOS mirrors. After your mirror is approved, you can do incremental rsyncs directly from rsync://msync.centos.org/CentOS/